# XSLT position before and after

Tags: xpath

```
<parent>
...
  <child>foo</child>
  <child current="true">current</child>
  <child>bar</child>
...
</parent>
```

How would I get the values of the children before and after the @current child (i.e. output foo and bar)? I'll be outputting Prev/Next links using those values. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't XSLT the language? I guess Xpath then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
child[@current='true']/preceding-sibling::child[1]

child[@current='true']/following-sibling::child[1]
```